# scale rotating boundingbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna-4.0

I recently started to develop a Windows Phone game with XNA. I have problem as you might have guessed collision detection. After looking up tutorials about all the types that can be achieved I decided I will go for the basic rectangular collision detection. I have a rotating sprite and a method that calculates the bounding box every time in the Update() method so I know where it's bounding box is then I simply check for intersection between all the lines of the box with all the lines of the other sprite's boxes. But since my box is appearing square shaped and my texture of that rotating sprite is Rectangular I wanna scale the bounding box so it will be closer to the texture's size. Here is what I have for calculating the corners of the rotating bounding box:

```
        double baseAngle = Math.Atan(this.Height / this.Width);
        double len = Math.Sqrt(this.Height * this.Height / 4 + this.Width * this.Width / 4);

        Vector2 tr = new Vector2((float)(Math.Sin(baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.X, (float)(Math.Cos(baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.Y);
        Vector2 tl = new Vector2((float)(Math.Sin(Math.PI - baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.X, (float)(Math.Cos(Math.PI - baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.Y);
        Vector2 bl = new Vector2((float)(Math.Sin(Math.PI + baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.X, (float)(Math.Cos(Math.PI + baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.Y);
        Vector2 br = new Vector2((float)(Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI - baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.X, (float)(Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI - baseAngle + this.Rotation) * len) + this.Position.Y);`
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you scale, it only appears bigger widht and height are same. so bounding box is same as for original. try multypllying height and width with scale number where you calculate bounding box.

and you cannot rotate bounding box, you will have to use [matrix.class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197911.aspx) but you can allways use circle collision.

circle collision

```
int circlesColliding(int x1, int y1, int radius1, int x2, int y2, int radius2) {
    //compare the distance to combined radii
    int dx = x2 - x1;
    int dy = y2 - y1;
    int radii = radius1 + radius2;
    if ((dx * dx) + (dy * dy) < radii * radii) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I rotate the sprite (as I am already doing) the bounding box is rotating with it. I draw lines between the corners of that bounding box and I can actually see it but I just wanna make it a bit smaller and since the corners are calculated all the time in the update method I don't know how to implement that :/

Comment: @Kanga ok i see, then you need polygon collision detection, because boundingbox and intersect are for non-rotated box models (that's why i suggested circle). so for collision try using (SAT) Separating Axis Theorem. here is example: http://xnatd.blogspot.com/2012/05/2d-collision-series-sat-part-1.html